# Confusion regarding str.format()

Tags: python, formatting

I am constructing a URL and injecting some params using `requests` library,

`QUERY_PARAMS['q'] = r'test="{}"'.format(0012000017421)`

This gives the expected:
`'test="1342185233"'`

But when I use the requests library to make a request like this:

```
result = requests.get(urlparse.urljoin(URL_TEST, URL_SEARCH), params=QUERY_PARAMS)
```

On my print statement I get a totally different number:

```
print('Searching with params: ', QUERY_PARAMS, ' on URL: ', result.url)

>>>('Searching with params: ', {'q': 'test="1342185233"', 'pretty_print': True, 'dataset': 'pod_nutrition_us'}, ' on URL: ', u'https://example.com/api/records/1.0/search?q=test%3D%221342185233%22&pretty_print=True&dataset=pod_nutrition_us')
```

How did this 1342185233 number come up when I use 0012000017421?

If, however, do this:

```
QUERY_PARAMS['q'] = r'test="0012000017421"'
```

This works correctly and the print statement above prints correctly what I want. Why does this occur?

Comment: `int('0012000017421',8) == 1342185233 # True`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python2, a literal number starts with `0` is in octal.

```
>> 011 == 9
True
```

In Python3, it's slightly different,

> octal literals must now be specified with a leading "0o" or "0O" instead of "0";

which reduces the chance of making mistake.

Comment: I understand, so how do I have the number represented as decimal with the leading zeroes in place?

Comment: Using a string like `'0012000017421'`

Comment: I cannot use a string since this static number is used for testing and will be replaced with a variable. `str(variable)` seems to also have the same problem.

Comment: How about removing the prefix 0s?

Comment: Will not work in my case. I have to send the number with the zeroes.

Comment: If you do want the 0s in your query parameter, and you have to use integer literal, and the parameter is fixed length with `13` digits, you can try `r'test="{:013}"'.format(12000017421)`

Comment: So it looks like I will have to manually check the variable for leading zeros and remove them I guess. Thanks for your time

Comment: Well, format number in octal `r'test="{:013o}"'.format(0012000017421)`

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the number instead of string in the format function. And since your number starts with zero, Python2 considers it to be an octal.

You can add quotes around your number and pass it in format function.

```
QUERY_PARAMS['q'] = r'test="{}"'.format('0012000017421')
```

This should do the work.